# What does the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n^3-n}$ converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the series converges. My questions is to what. I tried seeing if it was a telescoping series:
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n^3-n} =  2\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{1}{n^2-1}-\frac{1}{n})$ but it doesn't seem to cancel any terms. Thoughts?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$

Answer (score 5):

That partial fraction
is incorrect.

$\frac1{n^3-n}
=\frac1{n(n^2-1)}
=\frac1{n(n-1)(n+1)}
=\frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n-1}+\frac{c}{n+1}
$.

Find $a, b, $ and $c$
and then see if things
cancel out in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is telescoping series: the term is $\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}$, so all the terms cancel except the initial $-\frac{2}{2}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Cipra All my signs the wrong way around. Now fixed. Many thanks.